# Android layout manager shows something wrong

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, editor

I have a really strange problem to solve. After using the layout manager for weeks, it's suddenly "stopped" working. Although I've read the others problems claimed that it doesn't show anything, and even i tried some of the solutions mentioned there, my layout manager is not empty. Actually, its title says Android menu, and as i see, i could build a menu here.

Please note, that not a single layout will be displayed even in my old projects.
Also, if I manually edit the xml file a new line will be added automatically:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu>
```

I think this is not an error, but a setting i could not find.